# How to get PID of a process running in Windows using Java

Tags: java, pid, oshi

I have used OSHI libraries available, but the getProcessID function is not working. I need to find the PID of a process entered by the user.

I have now used this code

```java
public static String getProcessPID(String processName, boolean... ignoreLetterCase) {
    String pid = "";
    boolean ignoreCase = true;
    if (ignoreLetterCase.length > 0) {
        ignoreCase = ignoreLetterCase[0];
    }

    // Acquire the Task List from Windows
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("tasklist.exe");
    Process process;
    try {
        process = processBuilder.start();
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
        return "";
    }
    // Read the list and grab the desired PID
    String tasksList;
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(process.getInputStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A")) {
        int counter = 0;
        String strg = "";
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            strg = scanner.nextLine();

            // Uncomment the line below to print the current Tasks List to Console Window.
            // System.out.println(strg);

            if (!strg.isEmpty()) {
                counter++;
                if (counter > 2) {
                    if (ignoreCase) {
                        if (strg.toLowerCase().contains(processName.toLowerCase())) {
                            String[] tmpSplit = strg.split("\\s+");
                            pid += (pid.isEmpty()) ? tmpSplit[1] : ", " + tmpSplit[1];
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (strg.contains(processName)) {
                            String[] tmpSplit = strg.split("\\s+");
                            pid += (pid.isEmpty()) ? tmpSplit[1] : ", " + tmpSplit[1];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return pid;
}
```

This fails for processes with multiple instances running such as Chrome. So, how do I get Parent ProcessID or a process with a space in between the name?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You haven't mentioned which Java version you use as later versions make this easier. Probably a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58146630/how-to-get-os-process-details-of-specific-application-using-sigar-or-oshi-apis-i).

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use tasklist.exe.  Use the [ProcessHandle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html) class.  Not only will your code be shorter and easier to maintain, it will also work on systems other than Windows, with no additional effort.

Also, don’t use a varargs argument when you only want zero or one values.  Use method overloads for that.

```
public static OptionalLong getProcessPID(String processName) {
    return getProcessPID(processName, true);
}

public static OptionalLong getProcessPID(String processName, boolean ignoreLetterCase) {
    Predicate<String> matcher = cmd -> (ignoreLetterCase
        ? cmd.toLowerCase().contains(processName.toLowerCase())
        : cmd.contains(processName));

    try (Stream<ProcessHandle> processes = ProcessHandle.allProcesses()) {
        return processes
            .filter(p -> p.info().command().filter(matcher).isPresent())
            .mapToLong(p -> p.pid())
            .findFirst();
    }
}
```